# can anybody help me in making an android client to use WiseTrend OCR webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

I basically want to make an android app for image to text converter. The url http://www.wisetrend.com/WiseTREND_Online_OCR_API_v2.0.htm provides sample demo on how to use that with C#. but i am not very much comfortable with using webservices in java.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have a look [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient&ei=IY86TufEAZOBhQfL_dGPAg&usg=AFQjCNHi05OuSkTSS2cSahovWdZ8glXzBw)

You will use httpclient to POST a request.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(....

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(XML,HTTP.UTF_8);
se.setContentType("text/xml");

httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");

httppost.setEntity(se);

BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse)

httpclient.execute(httppost);
```